# Pandas GroupBy by Element and everything else

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

Im having a hard time using Pandas groupby.  Say I have the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

I want to do a groupby operation to get group all A's together and all not A's together, so something like this:

```
df2.groupby(<something>).groups
Out[1]: {'A': [2, 3], 'not A': [0, 1, 4]}
```

I've tried things like sending in a function but couldn't get anything to work.  Is this possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the groupby operations are possibly the most useful and in my opnion the worst explained in the documentation.

I think you were on to something when you decided to try to do this with a function. For me that is the best way, as the function is abstract and so can be used over and over again, if you want to vary what you are doing but change the parameters. The answer provided by Dan Allan is definitely how I would proceed and is the most elegant, but for your reference this is how you would achieve what you want to do using a function.

```
def GroupFunc(x, df, col, Value):
    if df[col][x] == Value:
        return "Group 1" 
    else:
        return "Group 2"

DFGrouped = df2.groupby(lambda x: GroupFunc(x, df2, 'X', 'A'))
```

The thing to understand is that any function passed as a group key is called once per index value with the return values being used as the group names. Therefore in this example when you call the function x is the index value, and then the remaining arguments are the dataframe you are interested in, the column you are working with and the value to test.

Note that the whole of the above could also be achieved in a single lineby using an anonymous function:

```
DFGrouped = df2.groupby(lambda x: 'Group 1' if df2.X[x] == 'A' else 'Group 2')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Woody, on second look, I think I like your solution the best because it scales well to multiple groups which is where I was headed.  Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [3]: df2.groupby(df2['X'] == 'A').groups
Out[3]: {False: [0, 1, 4], True: [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 3):

to expand @Dan Allan answer a bit - if you want to name your groups, you can use [numpy.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create mapping array:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
>>> m = np.where(df2['X'] == 'A', 'A', 'not A')
>>> df2.groupby(m).groups
{'A': [2, 3], 'not A': [0, 1, 4]}
```

To check if df2['X'] is either A or B, you can use `df2['X'].isin(['A', 'B'])` instead of `df2['X'] == 'A'`, or more clumsy `np.logical_or(df2['X'] == 'A', df2['X'] == 'B')`

Comment: how couild you expand this to where df2['X'] == 'B' also? m = np.where(df2['X'] == 'A' or df2['X'] == 'B', 'Group1', 'Group2) does not seem to work....?